# sql insert procedure: insert values into table and control if value is existing in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have little problem. I am trying to insert value into table. This is working. But I would like to control if value id_trainer is existing in another table. I want this -> execute insertClub(1, 5, 'someName'); -> and if id_trainer 5 not exists in table Trainer, procedure gives me message about this. (I tried to translate it into eng. lng., so you can find some gramm. mistakes)

```
create or replace procedure insertClub
(id_club in number, id_trainer in number, clubName in varchar2)
is
begin
declare counter number;

select count(*) into counter from trianer tr where tr.id_trainer = id_trainer;

if counter = 0 then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Trainer with this ID not exists');
end if;

insert into club values(id_club, id_trainer, clubName);
exception
  when dup_val_on_index then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dup ID');

end;
/
```

Comment: Probably You have problem because parameter name is the same as column name. You have to change to: `where tr.id_trainer = insertClub.id_trainer` or change parameter name to something like `p_id_trainer` or `l_id_trainer`.

Comment: I tried change it. But nothing happened. It has some problem with variable or select because select is underlined. And I have "expecting := . ( @ % ;" after "show err;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some error in the procedure. Please run below code to create procedure:

```
create or replace procedure insertClub
(id_club in number, id_trainer in number, clubName in varchar2)
is
 counter number;
begin
select count(*) into counter from trianer tr where tr.id_trainer = id_trainer;

if counter = 0 then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Trainer with this ID not exists');
end if;

insert into club values(id_club, id_trainer, clubName);
exception
  when dup_val_on_index then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dup ID');

end;
/
```

Comment: Yes. Do not forget to put commit after insert statement. Please let me know if you still face any problem

Comment: Yes, it´s working. Tests were successful. Thanks. Now I can face to another problems. .. Please tell me. Why is "declare" wrong"? (My study notes are probably full of mistakes.)

Comment: The DECLARE keyword is not required in PL/SQL subprograms (procedures and&#160;functions). The section contained within&#160;IS&#160;and&#160;BEGIN&#160;is known as the Declarative section. Note that&#160;TRIGGER&#160;requires the DECLARE section to be declared explicitly.

Also, check this two site for details:
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/procedures.php
</br>
http://psoug.org/definition/DECLARE.htm